# Can I limit the range of server.port=0 for Zuul?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have a Spring application annotated with `@EnableZuulProxy`. The port of this application is configured in application.yml as

```
server:
  port: 0
```

This works as expected to get a random port.

Question: Can I limit the range of this port?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/9403